# How can i configure apache server to Proxy to http://localhost:3000/ and exclude some URL?

Tags: php, regex, apache, proxy, ubuntu-18.04

I want my Laravel to use Client side Nuxt JS and use Laravel as backend admin-panel and api(s).

This is my code to proxy Laravel project to Nuxt JS but it's not properly working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nuxt.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nuxt/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPassMatch /^(admin-panel)(.*)$ !

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    LogLevel debug
 </VirtualHost>
```

I want to exclude "admin-panel" and "api" routes from hitting the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem

I am posting my apache2 config code. Might be this can be helpful for any.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName blog.net

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public

  <LocationMatch "/"> 
    allow from all 
    Satisfy any 
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
  </LocationMatch>

  <LocationMatch "/admin-panel/*"> 
    allow from all 
    Satisfy any 
    ProxyPass http://localhost/blog/public
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/blog/public
  </LocationMatch>

  <LocationMatch "/admin/*"> 
    allow from all 
    Satisfy any 
    ProxyPass http://localhost/blog/public
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/blog/public
  </LocationMatch>

  <LocationMatch "/api/*"> 
    allow from all 
    Satisfy any 
    ProxyPass http://localhost/blog/public
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/blog/public
  </LocationMatch>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**and in laravel routes/web.php file write the**

```
\URL::forceRootUrl(env('APP_URL'));
```

to use project URL not proxy URL

Answer (score 1):

- You might want to locate your `httpd.conf` inside your apache directory. Then, make an original copy and keep it.
- Then, search for VirtualHost, you might find something similar to:

---

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
   ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nuxt/public"
    ServerName localhost

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    <Directory "/var/www/html/nuxt/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        MultiviewsMatch Any
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make the changes, however you wish. You might want to make sure, this is correct before you add:

```
ProxyPassMatch /^(admin-panel)(.*)$ !
```

Maybe, you want something like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(admin-panel)(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/
```

After each changes in `httpd.conf`, you might want to restart apache and test to see if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ProxyPassMatch` directive try just excluding each url from your proxy pass:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPass /admin-panel !
ProxyPass /api !
```

There is probably a way to combine them into one line with regular expression as well, something like: `ProxyPass ^/(admin-panel|api)(.*)$ !`

Comment: Thanks, but In this case my admin-panel  url not working

Comment: @NitinSinghNaruka Of course it won't work, you asked to exclude the **admin-panel** route. If you remove the `ProxyPass /admin-panel !`  from you Apache conf it will work again.

Comment: I mean admin panel not handling with Laravel