# What is wrong in my apache2 virtual host conf?

Tags: php, regex, apache

What is wrong in my apache2 virtual host conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.net

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public

ProxyPass /admin-panel/ !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to blog.net is working fine and proxy to http://localhost:3000/ but if I go to blog.net/admin-panel this is not working is always going to http://localhost:3000/.

Comment: [[Solved] Visit the link to get proper configuration code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142034/6769934)